# GDAL errors with conda installation

Tags: python, gdal, installation, osgeo, conda

I installed gdal using conda (Windows) with 'conda create -n pygeo gdal h5py python=3.8'. After activating with conda activate pygeo, and attempting to write out a geotiff using gdal_translate, I get get the error shown below.

Could anyone point out where I am going wrong and how to fix it?

```
return _gdal.TranslateInternal(*args)
RuntimeError: Failed to process SRS definition: EPSG:4326
```

My gdal_translate use:

from osgeo import gdal.

```
def processHD5(inputHD5, layer, outputRaster):    ## Open HDF file
    hdflayer = gdal.Open(inputHD5, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
    subhdflayer = hdflayer.GetSubDatasets()[layer][0]
    rlayer = gdal.Open(subhdflayer, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)    
    HorizontalTileNumber = int(rlayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["HorizontalTileNumber"])
    VerticalTileNumber = int(rlayer.GetMetadata_Dict()["VerticalTileNumber"])    
    WestBoundCoord = (10*HorizontalTileNumber) - 180
    NorthBoundCoord = 90-(10*VerticalTileNumber)    
    EastBoundCoord = WestBoundCoord + 10
    SouthBoundCoord = NorthBoundCoord - 10    
    EPSG = "-a_srs EPSG:4326" #WGS84 
    translateOptionText = EPSG+" -a_ullr " + str(WestBoundCoord) + " " + str(NorthBoundCoord) + " " + str(EastBoundCoord) + " " + str(SouthBoundCoord)
    translateoptions = gdal.TranslateOptions(gdal.ParseCommandLine(translateOptionText))
    gdal.Translate(outputRaster,rlayer, options=translateoptions)
```

I also changed EPSG = "-a_srs EPSG:4326" to EPSG = "-projwin_srs srs_def_epsg" and defined the srs_def_epsg separately. I still get the same error.

Comment: `import gdal` is now depreciated. `from osgeo import gdal` is the right way. How and from where did you run `gdal_translate`?

Comment: @AmanBagrecha thanks! So import works. I have edited the question to show gdal_translate use and the error.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chat like thanks and other statements of appreciation within your posts.

Comment: If you are attempting to convert HDF file to GeoTIFF, simply use `gdalwarp` instead of translate because I see you want to set EPSG:4326 projection to the GeoTIFF